# Delphi Script Engine auto generate code based on file

Tags: delphi

Is there a way in which you can generate Delphi code from a file type which you define and know the definition of the language inside?

Basically I would like to perform the same operation as occurs in C# with some tools. Something like SpecFlow where you define a .feature file and it generates the NUnit code to match the spec in that file.

Also a way to hook this in for each compile, and to have it automatically hook into the file types extension name. This means that when you add a .feature file into the project, it knows to generate a pas file for that .feature file based on the contents.

The only way I can think of doing this at present would be to write an extension for Delphi. Is there something simpler that I am missing?

I have found [Delphi Live Template Engine](https://bitbucket.org/NickHodges/delphi-live-template-engine/overview) by Nick Hodges which seems to get me part of the way, however the auto file generation and linkage is the missing piece.

Comment: Define your domain language, parse the input files, generate the code.

Comment: Understand the steps, but I was missing the middle part which integrates this in the build process. C# allows you to define processes which occur as you build, no need for extensions to IDE. Is there such a beast in Delphi which I am missing? Something like the process that is used to create TLB pas files. However in some cases I have to revert to a pre-build events command. Something I would prefer to avoid here as I want to add this new file type at will.

Comment: So make this clear in the question

Comment: Delphi has a command line option, just feed your code there and it will compile.